# How to get params values in mapStateToProps using react-router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I use react-router v4, react-router-dom, redux, and react-redux to make my app work.  But when I want to get the deckId, I cant get the params, it has only children prop in ownProps argument.

My Main component looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import * as reducers from './reducers';
reducers.routing = routerReducer;

import App from './components/App';
import VisibleCards from './components/VisibleCards';


const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers));

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store);

function run() {
let state = store.getState();
console.log(state);
render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <App>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/'/>
                <Route path='/deck/:deckId' component={VisibleCards}/>
            </Switch>
        </App>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
}

run();

store.subscribe(run);
```

And the App component like this

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';



const mapStateToProps = (props, { params: { deckId } }) => ({ deckId });

const App = ({ deckId, children }) => {
console.log(params);
return (
    <div className="app">
        <Sidebar/>
        <h1>Deck {deckId}</h1>
        {children}
    </div>
);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I used withRouter to connect redux to react-router but it doesn`t help either. What should I do ? 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The react-router `params` were moved from the component's `this.props.params` to `this.props.match.params`.

It looks like your `mapStatesToProps` needs to be updated to `ownProps.match.params.deckId`.